# In Haskell, waitForProcess is blocking Ctrl-C under Windows' cmd.exe

Tags: windows, haskell, interrupt-handling

I tried to run the following Haskell program in Windows' cmd.exe , while waitForProcess is being executed, pressing ctrl-c is not killing the program. But it works if running under MinGW shell. Any ideas?
(note: Windows does not come with a "sleep" command, I just wrote one myself.)

```
{-# Language OverloadedStrings #-}
import System.Process

main ∷ IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "sleeping"
  (_, _, _, pHandle) <-
    createProcess CreateProcess { 
          cmdspec = RawCommand "sleep" ["5"]
        , cwd = Nothing
        , env = Nothing
        , std_in = CreatePipe, std_out = CreatePipe, std_err = CreatePipe
        , close_fds = False
        , create_group = False
        } 
  waitForProcess pHandle
  putStrLn "all done"
```

Comment: What happens if you build with `-threaded`?

Comment: Same behaviour, I should have mentioned that before.

Answer (score 1):

It appears this is an issue with how mingw and cygwin handle consoles:

http://www.mail-archive.com/cygwin@cygwin.com/msg104921.html
http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.os.cygwin/135374

Answer (score 1):

```
module Main where

import System.Process

main = do callCommand "sleep 5"
       putStrLn "all done"
```

cmd.exe's sleep works fine running above code for me! Ctrl+C terminates too! Simpler functions for Common tasks are documented at [Hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/process-1.2.0.0/docs/System-Process.html#g:2).

Answer (score 0):

System sheduller don't get some time for thread, while it wait for event of a kernel's object.
Solution is to call waitForProcess from another thread, different from the main.